# Validating Debugging Configuration on PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using the latest PhpStorm on Windows. Following the instructions on

https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/06/debugging-vvv-vagrant-setup-with-phpstorm/

I was able to validate the connection.

However the I can't connect to PhpStorm from Chrome and X-debug helper. 
When I return to the validation I see the message from the error page.

The path on Windows to create validation script is

C:\Users\Adrian\Projects\vagrant\drupal

[image: error page]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed, that I can use the X-debug despite of this error.

This "issue" relates more to PHPStorm team rathen then stackoverflow.